# Typestate struct graph relations

Tags: rust

I have an (acyclic) tree structure using some structs. I want to codify the relations at the type-level so I can get guarantees on whether a given struct is a descendant of another.

Would it be possible to implement a macro- or blanket implementation for `DescendantOf<Ancestor>`? Or is there a way with associated types, even at arbitrary depth?

**Struct graph**

```rust
#[Derive(ParentChildRelation)]
struct GrandFather {
  father: Father
}

#[Derive(ParentChildRelation)]
struct Father {
  child: Child
}

#[Derive(ParentChildRelation)]
struct Child {}
```

**Relation traits**

```rust
// automatically implemented using Derive
pub trait ParentOf<Child> {}

// automatically implemented using Derive
pub trait ChildOf<Parent> where Parent: ParentOf<Self> {}

// automatically implemented using impl constraint

pub trait Descendant2<Root, Parent>
where
    Root: ParentOf<Parent>,
    Parent: ChildOf<Root> + ParentOf<Self>,
    Self: ChildOf<Parent>
{}

pub trait Descendant3<Root, GrandFather, Parent>
    where
        Root: ParentOf<GrandFather>,
        GrandFather: ChildOf<Root> + ParentOf<Parent>,
        Parent: ChildOf<GrandFather> + ParentOf<Self>,
        Self: ChildOf<Parent>
{

// and so on...
...
```

**Blanket implementations**

```rust
// blanket implement all variants 2, 3, n...
impl<Ancestor, GrandFather, Parent, T> Descendant3<Ancestor, GrandFather, Parent>
for T
    where
        Ancestor: ParentOf<GrandFather>,
        GrandFather: ChildOf<Ancestor> + ParentOf<Parent>,
        Parent: ChildOf<GrandFather> + ParentOf<T>,
        T: ChildOf<Parent>
{}

// this all works
...
```

My goal is being able to do something like:

```rust
fn test(descendant:Obj) where Obj: DescendantOf<GrandParent>
```

But I don't see a way of implementing a `DescendantOf<Ancestor>` trait based on the more extensive DescendantX<A, B, C, ...> traits, since:

```rust
// todo: this doesnt work... how do we now get DescendantOf<Ancestor> implemented for all *X variants? this results in 'the type parameter B, C is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates' error...
impl<T: Descendant3<Ancestor, B, C>, A, B, C> DescendantOf<Ancestor> for T {}
```

Comment: So at every level of the tree you want a different type?(this seems hard to use) And then you want to be able to call a function with a subset of those types?

Comment: What if you could have one struct that can be at any depth which is const generic over the depth. Then at the call site you could specify that it can be called with depth < 5 for example?

Comment: @Hadus No I don't neccessarily want a different type at every level of the tree, I just thought those variants could be used to encode the relations, after which a level-less DescendantOf<Node> could be implemented using a blanket impl.

The only thing I care about is being able to tell at compiletime whether a node is a descendant of a type. Depth doesn't matter. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Once const_generics are fully out this will be easy using them but until then you will have to generate loads of `impl`s. Something like this: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b077da6835a9c9dfe3a057680afbb07) But once const_generics is done then something like: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e32402bd3fd7646125af19f86cea7c52)